# how to find Substring up to specific character

Tags: c#, substring

How do I find a substring up to a specific character? What I would like is to find the substring of something similar to:

```
172.20.9.93\randDir
```

I want the IPAddress, or in other terms, everything up until the "\" if the "\" exists.
Is there a way to do this with substring or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: -1 for no research. Easily googlable.

Answer (score 6):

> I want the IPAddress, or in other terms, everything up until the "\" if the "\" exists.

Two options:

- Find the index of the first `\` using `IndexOf`, then use `Substring`

  ```
  int firstSlash = text.IndexOf('\\');
  string ipAddress = firstSlash == -1 ? text : text.Substring(0, firstSlash);
  ```
- Split by `\` using `String.Split`, and then take the first part

  ```
  string ipAddress = text.Split('\\')[0];
  ```

Comment: So it'd be something like `str.substring(0,str.IndexOf('\\');`

Comment: @user2568791: That would fail if there weren't any backslashes. See the code in my edit.

Comment: Thank you, I guess i never really thought about it failing.

Comment: if using `String.Split` Method, would I also need to check if it fails, or does it just split it into basically the exact same pre-existing string?

Comment: @user2568791: You're fine if you know the string isn't empty. I can't remember what happens if you call Split on an empty string.

Comment: Ok, it should never be an empty string anyways...thank ya

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regular expression match:

```
var input = @"172.20.9.93\rand";
var output = Regex.Match(input, @"\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b");
Console.WriteLine(output.Value);
```

Comment: that looks extremely complicated compared to a substring or a split

Comment: I agree, but in it's complexity also resides the validation of the IP address: if you have `999.999.999.999\randDir` as input, would you still like to capture the (invalid) IP address? Probably not the case to check this if the source of the input is actually logging real IP addresses, but still, in other cases it could save you from writing extra validation code.

Comment: It would never be invalid, seeing as I'm capturing the IP address from the machines using the InterNetwork Socket